# "Le ore 17:00" oppure "le 17:00 ore"?

Tags: word-usage, word-order

Come si deve dire e scrivere,  "le n:m ore" oppure "le ore n:m" (dove n indica le ore e  m indica i minuti)? Ad esempio, quale tra queste due frasi sarebbe la forma corretta?

> - La conferenza si terrà alle 17:00 ore.
> - La conferenza si terrà alle ore 17:00.

Cercando su Internet ho trovato esempi di tutte e due queste espressioni.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Senza ombra di dubbio il secondo (“ore 17:00”): il primo sembra frutto di un *template* mal programmato.

Se si tratta di un'ora tonda, meglio “...si terrà alle ore 17” (senza “00”), e ancora meglio e meno burocratichese “...si terrà alle 17”.

Comment: Risposta ineccepibile. Segnalo solo che, in passato, si soleva dire «A diciassett’ore», con preposizione semplice e con «ore» posposto, come in Gozzano («Per la partita, verso ventun’ore / giungeva tutto l’inclito collegio / politico locale», _La signorina Felicita_) o nei _Pagliacci_ di Leoncavallo («Un grande spettacolo a ventitré ore / prepara il vostr’umile e buon servitore!»), ma la denominazione, se non sbaglio, era legata all’antica suddivisione del giorno, da tramonto a tramonto («ora italica»).